# Why does nmap work but nnoremap not work to set up vim-easy-align shortcut?

Tags: key-bindings, plugin-easy-align

The [vim-easy-align plugin](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align) says to assign the following keymaps:

```
xmap ga <Plug>(EasyAlign)
nmap ga <Plug>(EasyAlign)
```

I thought these would work equally well with:

```
xnoremap ga <Plug>(EasyAlign)
nnoremap ga <Plug>(EasyAlign)
```

but it doesn't. I thought `map` is recursive and `noremap` is non-recursive, and since there is no recursion, they should behave identically here. Why not?

Answer (score 7):

Let's start with the difference between recursive mapping and non-recursive mapping.

In a recursive mapping (`nmap`, `xmap`, etc.), the keys you use in the right hand side of your mapping are used "as is". If they are already mapped at the time of execution those mappings are respected:

```
" here we remap b to work like B
nmap b B

" <F5> thus works like dB instead of db because it uses the new meaning of b
nmap <F5> db
```

In a non-recursive mapping (`nnoremap`, `xnoremap`, etc.), the keys in the right hand side are used in their original meaning. If they are already mapped at the time of execution those mappings are *not* respected:

```
" here we remap b to work like B
nmap b B

" <F5> works like db because it uses the original meaning of b
nnoremap <F5> db
```

`<Plug>(EasyAlign)` being a mapping, it is respected by recursive mappings and ignored by non-recursive ones.

**The rules are:**

- Use a recursive mapping if you want to use another mapping in your mapping.
- Use a non-recursive mapping if you don't.

Comment: What may be confusing (it was, for me) is that *defining* a `<Plug>` (i.e. mapping it to do something, as opposed to mapping some key combo *to* a `<Plug>`) will normally use the non-recursive forms, as recommended when you need to know exactly what action to expect. That's usually a task for plugin authors, but one can stumble upon such examples (e.g. in `usr_41.txt`)

Comment: Now to fix my 2778 line .vimrc xD